# MapServer - Os Open Data - Tutorial

Tags: mapserver, references, os-opendata

I have recently received my OS OpenData discs from Ordnance Survey, and for the last two evening tried to get this data into MapServer for ultimate use as a WMS for OpenLayers.

Safe to say I have struggled with how to get the data (.tif and .tfw) into a MapServer instance.

I have set Mapserver up correctly, in that I a directory structure such as:

```
MapServer
  data
  map
    mymapfile.map
  scripts
    gdal 
    ...
  tmp
```

I am able to browse to my localhost (Windows) and retrieve a sample graphic from MapServer, so I am fairly confident I have MapServer setup correctly.

http://mapserver.localhost.com/scripts/mapserv.exe?map=C:\MapServer\map\mapfiletest.map&mode=map&FORMAT=image/png&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256

That is a sample of the Url I am using.

I have obviously Googled a fair bit over the last few evenings, but I dont seem to be finding any specific information to take me forward with getting my OS OpenData (streetview as an example) available through MapServer.

Does anyone have any links or specific information to help me out?

Comment: Joanna Cook (Archaeogeek) has do a slideshow on how she has done it using opensource tool (postgis) backend http://www.slideshare.net/Archaeogeek/consuming-and-publishing-ordnance-survey-open-data-with-open-source-software

Comment: 'mode=map' is incorrect for a WMS